# C++ Generating a Unique ID

Tags: c++

I am Having trouble generating a unique id for each of my objects.

My objects are a song object witch has variables artist, genre etc.

so in my **song.h** file under private I have

```
private:
   int m_ID;
   static unsigned int IDSeed;
```

in my **song.cpp** file I have

```
Song::Song()
{
    static unsigned int IDSeed = 0;
    m_ID = IDSeed++;

}

Song::Song(constructor variables)
{

    m_ID = IDSeed++;

}
```

The main error I am getting now is **"unresolved external symbol private static unsigned int Song::IDSeed"**

Comment: If you construct them all with the default constructor (`Song a; Song b; Song c;`), then you're setting all the IDs to zero.

Comment: _so in my song.h file under private I have_  Why you don't just show your song class declaration? Second, `static unsigned int IDSeed;` is different from `unsigned int IDSeed = 0;`

Comment: Can't you simply use the memory address of the object (`reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(this)`) as the unique ID? No two objects alive will share an address (although an object may be re-using the address of a past, now dead, one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems to me that `IDSeed` must be the same across `Song` objects, then, it must be declared static. So, in your **song.h** file, you must have something like that:

```
class Song {
    int m_ID;
    static unsigned int IDSeed;
    static int helper_seed() { IDSeed++; return IDSeed;}
    (...)
};
```

Now, you need to initialize your static member. So, in **song.cpp**:

```
unsigned int Song::IDSeed = 0;
```

Now, on each constructor of `Song` object, you can do something like this:

```
Song::Song()
{
    m_ID = helper_seed();    
}

Song::Song(constructor variables)
{
    m_ID = helper_seed();
}
```

Comment: I am now having trouble with the "static unsigned int Song::IDSeed = 0;"  I am getting the error a storage class may not be specified here

Comment: Thank you very much I got it working. I had to remove the static keyword from IDSeed in song.cpp for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the memory address of the object -
 `reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(this)` - as the unique ID, as long as the ID just has to be unique amongst all currently alive objects.

No two objects alive will share an address (although an object may be re-using the address of a past, now dead, one).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `static unsigned int IDSeed;` does nothing. `unsigned int IDSeed = 0;` is a "usuall" class (instance) variable and it will be set to zero everytime you init your class. If you want to have persistent value, you must have this variable static. Also, you can remove  `static unsigned int IDSeed;` from `Song()`

Comment: Ok when i do that i get the error  "a member with an in-class initializer must be const" If I place const in front of static unsigned int I get  the error "++ needs na I_Value"